# css pseudo elements on html option tag

Tags: html, css, forms, pseudo-element

is there a way to add a css pseudo element on a html option tag?

I have tried adding specifically to an disabled option but I have found it to be troublesome also on enabled option tags.

I tried the following approach:

css:

```
option:disabled span::before{
  color: red;
  content: "Not Available";
}
```

html:

```
<select>
   <option disabled><span></span> some text </option>
</select>
```

eventually I didnt manage to make it work. any thoughts on how to approach this properly?

Answer (score 0):

The **:before** applies to a child element and **option** does not have children, so the answer is no.

> **::before (:before)
> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.**

Reference - [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

**However, you can use javascript to replace the value.**